# Why the following code is printing b =5 instead of b =4 as it decremented after the operation?

Tags: c, numbers, increment, decrement

after the operation, b should equal to  5, then be should post decrement resulting b = 5, can anyone explain why this is not happening?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
   int a =2, b=3;
   b=a++ + b--;
   printf("a=%d  b=%d\n", a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are attempting to change `b` twice in the same expression

```
b = <something>;    // change b
    /*   b--  */    // change b
```

The order of the changes is not specified.